# I need to use a nested for loop to display a 10 by 10 grid of randomly generated Xs and Os

Tags: java

```
int[][] grid = new int[10][10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        // fill in
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far. I know I need to add in Math.Random, then set X = 0 and O = 1. I'm just very lost and confused. I'm in no way a good java coder and for me this is too advanced.

Comment: You're getting there. Have a read of the Random doco and see if you can get it to generate a sequence of zeroes and ones. Then set `grid[i][j]` to `X` or `O` depending on the random value.

Answer (score 1):

```
char[][] grid = new char[10][10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        grid[i][j] = "XO".charAt((int)Math.round(Math.random()));
    }
}
```

[`String#charAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) gets a character by the index. (So 0 returns X and 1 returns O)

[`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()) returns a random Double between 0 and 1, and with [`Math.round()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)) you round that number to the nearest whole number. (So either 0 or 1) which is used to give to the `charAt()` as parameter.

You do still need to cast the outcome of `Math.round()` as an `int` because it will return a long.

Comment: If we could use `java.util.Random` instead of forced dependency on `Math.random`, then imho `random.nextBoolean() ? "X" : "O"` might look better, with initialisation before the loop.